# html/css positioning -- like facebook

Tags: html, css, positioning

I made my "header" div position: fixed, but now my gray and orange divs moved up to the top instead of starting right under the header div.

I want my gray and orange divs to be 100% of the page height **after** the header **if** there the text doesn't pass the screen, **else** I want the divs to be 100% of the text height. (example in jsfiddle)

How can I make this possible?

```
#header {
position: fixed;
background-color: #a6c7ec;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
top: 0px;
float: top;
opacity: 0%;
```

}

Here is my **jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/xwwo2deq/

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support? ... Will IE9 and up + 3 versions back on all other major browsers be ok?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this `css` to the orange and gray div to make the divs come below the header

```
margin-top:50px;
```

Then to make the div height the same as the height of the text do this

```
height:auto;
```

Now if you don't want the div to be more than 100% of the device height use this

```
max-height:100%;
```